# I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04, now I can't browse the internet

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, internet, connection

I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04, now I can't browse the internet. When I go to Firefox, it say "server not found". I try different websites, I go the same thing. I have my Ethernet cable plug in right, when I plug the Ethernet cable to a Windows computer the internet works fine.

Comment: Are you under a proxy?

Comment: Have you checked your DNS settings?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to figure it out what's causing the problem. You may try in your browser to access a website not by a domain name, but by ip, ex: instead of google.com you could write 74.125.225.8 and if in this case it will work means that the problem is in the DNS. Otherwise you could see the configuration of your network interfaces by issuing the command `ifconfig` or `ifconfig eth0` if assuming that your Ethernet card is `eth0`.

In order to find the dns server assigned to your server issue this command: `nmcli dev list | grep DNS`. If there is no DNS you could add one (ex. google's free dns 8.8.8.8). In order to add a dns you should add a line like the one below to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

`prepend domain-name-servers x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y;` , where x.x.x.x or y.y.y.y is the dns server.